# Using VBA to export excel table data into Access DB - Endless issues with "INSERT INTO"

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

My colleagues use an Excel tracker to track tickets they are resolving and I want to implement a system where they can all upload their trackers to a central access database stored in a shared folder.
I have the macro set up and it works fine once or twice, but them seemingly for no reason it stops working with the error message:

*Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)':
The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'F13'. Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again.*

I have verified time and time again that all of the fields in my excel table match up with the fields in my Access DB and are spelled correctly (in fact I don't even have a field name 'F13' in either the excel table or the DB, and if I introduce one to satisfy the error message it instead says there is an unknown field name 'F14', and so on)

I have no idea where this phantom field is coming from that it's looking for.

Here is my code:

```
    Public Sub UploadToAccessDB()

'Skip operation if table contains no data
If ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListRows.Count = 1 Then
    MsgBox ("There is no data to upload")
    GoTo Skip
    Else
    End If


'Import tracker table rows to access
  Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  dbPath = " Redacted to protect the innocent :-P "                 'filepath of target access DB
  dbWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  dbWs = Application.ActiveSheet.Name
  scn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
  dsh = "[" & Application.ActiveSheet.Name & "$]"
  cn.Open scn


  ssql = "INSERT INTO Tracker ([Ticket URL], [Item / Reason], [Date Created], [Date Resolved / HandOff], [Handed Off to], [Keeper's Login], [Category], [Site], [Processing Time], [Tracker Upload Date], [Uploaded By], [Team] ) "      'Field names from tracker
  ssql = ssql & "SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "]." & dsh


  cn.Execute ssql            ' < Where the error is occurring


MsgBox ("Tracker uploaded to database")


Skip:

End Sub
```

I believe this is a bug with access, does anybody know of any workaround or another approach which side steps this issue?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Eh... Your query doesn't even include the text `INSERT INTO`. If you've modified your query, please include the full text. Also, please provide sample data. This error can occur if the amount of columns queried doesn't match the amount of columns present.

Comment: If you're doing an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM` I would advise you to change your SELECT statement to explicitly specify the columns you want.  F13 sounds like Excel is auto-generating a column name for a field in column 13 of your worksheet.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Apologies, I accidentally deleted the statement while changing the table target name. I amended my original post

And Joe, thanks for the input, I will try this and report back

Comment: How many columns are populated in the source excel sheet?  You may need to specify the range, as the error is happening after field 12, as you have 12 fields in the Insert statement

Comment: I'd suggest making sure the used range on your spreadsheet is correct - have the code delete extra columns and re-save the spreadsheet before attempting to import.  I'm guessing your colleagues are using extra columns which they then delete - might be something as trivial as entering a formula to quickly add up some figures before they type the final figure in - it will add an extra column to your used range though.  Also go with @Joe - name your columns.

Comment: I'd also not import directly to the _Tracker_ table.  It's easy to enter rubbish on a spreadsheet that the database won't accept.  For example, a date may have been entered as "18th June 2018" which won't format as a date, or even "18/06/3018" -  only a slight typo, but it's 1000 years out and will be accepted by the database.

Comment: @Joe This resolved my error and it now imports correctly, thanks a bunch for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that you have a number of problems with the approach as stated earlier in comments by  Nathan_Sav and  Darren Bartrup-Cook.

1. Firstly I'd write some code that opens and cleans the worst errors from the spreadsheets (dates that aren't in date format, extra columns etc, column names with spaces in them) in VBA. 
   e.g. this is a routine that will fix most dates (except the ones that are formatted as text)

`

```
 Function FixDateInCell(DataCell As Excel.Range, CellOffset As Long)

  Dim tmpDate As Variant
  Dim TheDatecell As Excel.Range

 Set TheDatecell = DataCell.Offset(0, CellOffset)

 'Date of Last Inspection....
  If IsPrettyVacant(TheDatecell.Value) Then 'if there is a date
      TheDatecell.Value = Null 'blanks and spaces can result in errors during import
  ElseIf (TheDatecell.Value) = 0 Or (TheDatecell.Value) = 1 Then
      TheDatecell.Value = Null ''blanks can result in errors during import

  ElseIf (IsDate(TheDatecell.Value) = True) Then 'this returns TRUE for dates as text
      tmpDate = TheDatecell.Value
      If TypeName(tmpDate) = "Date" Then
        'do nothing it's a true date, we don't need to fix it
      Else
        TheDatecell.Value = DateValue(TheDatecell.Value) 'fix it
      End If
  ElseIf Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(TheDatecell.Value) Then
      On Error Resume Next
      If IsError(DateValue(TheDatecell.Value)) Then GoTo CantFix:
       'Don't attempt to convert it to a date
       'MsgBox "DateValue returns:" & DateValue(TheDatecell.Value), vbOKOnly
       'newdate() = Split(TheDatecell.Value, "/")

  End If
CantFix:

End Function`
```

2. Secondly I'd import the spreadsheet to a table you have created earlier with all the data types (except Dates) set to 'Long Text'. Then try and process the data or import it into another table (and stuff that can't be imported will just be left behind)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will definitely adopt this approach!
Previously I was validating with excel but this is a much more reliable method